# mongo connection refused osx

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongo.  I ran the following:

```
 $sudo chown -R [username] /usr/local
~ $sudo chmod -R u+w /usr/local
~ $brew link mongodb
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.2... 14 symlinks created
```

I ran `mongo` and got the following:

```
~ $mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
2015-04-14T09:21:29.095-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-04-14T09:21:29.097-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing - same error and everything. I'm on Yosemite, 10.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a db address,

```
$ mongo <db-address>
```

mongo gets lost in the woods. If you want a mongo shell without a db,

```
$ mongo -nodb
```

does the trick.

If you're running locally, you probably either didn't specify a port (if the server isn't running on the default port 27107) or you just don't have a server running. The mongo command starts a shell, not the server. You need to

```
$ mongod --dbpath <path to data directory>
```

to get the server running. Once it's up,

```
$ mongo
```

should run locally with no problems.